# How to get CefSharp to work with configuration AnyCPU in vs common library

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have created a class library project with WPF windows in it. In one WPF window I want to get a CefSharp browser. My project should be with configuration *AnyCPU*. In different tutorials I saw that one of the points to tune *AnyCPU* configuration in an executable project with CefSharp is to set (*csproj*)

```
<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
```

But in class library projects, this property is disabled. 
How can I enable AnyCPU Support for CefSharp in my class library?

Comment: CefSharp uses lots and lots of unmanaged code.  So it is not AnyCPU at all, you must make a choice.  Writing two installers that deploy the respective biness of those unmanaged DLLs is sensible, having to support both is, well, not.  Why programmers like CefSharp is still an unanswered question btw, WebBrowser doesn't hassle them like that.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Comment: Use option two or three

Comment: @amaitland thanks for your reply. With option two when i add cefSharp references to my project i should add dll that are in cefsharp x86 folder (cefSharpCore.dll and so on)?

Comment: The `nuget` package should add the references for you.

Comment: @amaitland unfourtunately references were not be added by nuget package

Comment: The `nuget` package should copy the files to the executing projects bin directory. If you have to manually add references for whatever reason then `x86` will allow you to use the designer, just make sure they aren't set to `Copy Local`.

Comment: One reason for using CefSharp rather than WebBrowser is that CefSharp supports embedded videos and WebBrowser doesn't. However, CefSharp does not support all common video formats due to proprietary nature of most video codecs. So far I've found that webm format works, and mov, mp4, avi do not.

Answer (score 8):

See the Documentation: [General Usage Guide](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#anycpu-support)

There are several solutions to enable AnyCPU Support. I have used the following:

First, install the dependencies via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/).

Then, add `<CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>true</CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>` to the first `PropertyGroup` of the `.csproj` file containing the `CefSharp.Wpf` *PackageReference* for the `CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser` Control.

Now, write an Assembly Resolver to find the correct unmanaged DLLs depending on the current architecture:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;

private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("CefSharp"))
    {
        string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2)[0] + ".dll";
        string architectureSpecificPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
            Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
            assemblyName);

        return File.Exists(architectureSpecificPath)
            ? Assembly.LoadFile(architectureSpecificPath)
            : null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Finally, initialize CefSharp with at least these settings:

```cs
var settings = new CefSettings()
{
    BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
        Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
        "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe")
};
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Comment: What does this mean: `to the first PropertyGroup of the .csproj file`? Which file do I have to add `<CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>true</CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>`?

Comment: @Jonathan, you have to add that line to the Project-File containing the dependency to `CefSharp.Wpf`. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714.

Comment: Where would I put the code you are mentioning here?

Comment: @ed22 somewhere executed once before initializing the Control, e.g. in the `App` _c'tor_, see example https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/demo/anycpu/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs